# How do you do Numpy.eye in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

How to create the np.eye function in JavaScript? Or what would be the numpy.eye equivalent in JavaScript?

I would like a function that creates the "Identity matrix" in 2d dimensions, and you can change the number of rows, columns and the index of the diagonal.
https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html

This doesn't take care of M,N,k
@Andy

```
function eye(n){
var t=[];
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
var p=[]
for(var j=0;j<n;j++){
p.push(j==i?1:0)
}
t.push(p)
}}
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This doesn't take care of M,N,k

You are almost there, just have to put the extra parameters there, like the outer loop (rows) runs to `N`, the inner loop (columns) runs to `M`, and the comparison would be `j-i===k`:

```js
function eye(N,M,k) {
  var t = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var p = []
    for (var j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      p.push(j - i === k ? 1 : 0)
    }
    t.push(p)
  }
  return t;
}

let NMk=prompt("N,M,k").split(",").map(x=>parseInt(x));
console.log(eye(...NMk).map(x=>x.join()));
```

Try entering something like `3,3,0` ("classic") or `2,3,1` (a "fancy" one) when asked.
(And don't worry about the snippet printing strings, that's just the `join()` , to keep output small, and without much coding).

Comment: I tried `function eye(N,M=N,k=0) {...` it actually worked.